# How do I understand if my index contains data?

Tags: vertex-ai-search

I'm using Gen App Builder to build a search tool for a website. I've managed to configure my DNS to index that site and the indexing process seems to have completed.

How can I tell if my index contains data? Are there any other ways to troubleshoot this issue or otherwise understand *what* data I have in my index?

After configuring my site's DNS to establish ownership I expected the indexing process to result in a search that returns relevant information to natural language questions.

However, when I try to preview a search, or use a curl command, I never receive results, even for questions that I would expect to have relevant results on the site's main page.

[screenshot of the site showing a successful index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz4wo.png)

[screenshot showing no results in the preview search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnkB9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code sample to [List all documents in a data store](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/samples/genappbuilder-list-documents).

Note - This won't work for Website data stores that use standard indexing. Based on your screenshot, you're using advanced indexing, so it should be fine.

You can also use this Jupyter Notebook [github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/conversation/data-store-status-checker/data_store_checker.ipynb](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/blob/main/conversation/data-store-status-checker/data_store_checker.ipynb) to check the indexing status and the included URLs.

Answer (score -1):

Let me share with you a [GitHub topic](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/blob/main/conversation/data-store-status-checker/data_store_checker.ipynb) that might help you with your use case.

You can also consider availing [Generative AI support package](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/getting-support) to better discuss your needs.

Here are some other resources that might be of help to you.

- [Get started with Recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/try-personalize#request_indexing_of_your_website_data)
- [Create Recommendations data store](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-data-store-recommendations)

Comment: did the ai make this?

Comment: Nope. Apologies if it sounded like one.

Comment: Good deal sorry for the mixup.